# Python: Generating a new name based on value in multiple dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop

Relatively new to python, apologies if the question/script is verbose and vague. The script below returns the key and value of the team name searched (Ex: 2, Charlotte Hornets); however, I would also like it to return the league name it's in as well. Such as 'nfl', 'nba', 'mlb'; based on the dictionary it's found in (Ex: 2, Charlotte Hornets, nba). Been working on this for a while, but can't find a dynamic solution. Thanks for the help in advance!

```
NFL_Teams = {1: "Arizona Cardinals", 2: "Atlanta Falcons", 3: "Baltimore Ravens"}
NBA_Teams = {1:'Washington Wizards', 2:'Charlotte Hornets', 3: 'Atlanta Hawks'}
MLB_Teams = {1: 'Los Angeles Dogers', 2: 'Cincinnati Reds', 3: 'Toronto Blue Jays'}    

def Standings(reply):
    def dictionary_search(name, dictionary):
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            if value == name:
                return True # Boolean to show if team name is in merged dictionaries. 
            if key == name:
                pass # Used as a throw-away variable

    for single_dictionary in (NFL_Teams, NBA_Teams, MLB_Teams):
        if dictionary_search(reply, single_dictionary):
            for key, value in single_dictionary.items():
                if reply == value:
                    print(key, value)
            break
    else:
        print('Please Try Again')

Standings('Charlotte Hornets')
```

Comment: You basically want to get the name of the variable that holds the data. You can't do this (well, not without some weird trickery), but you can just make a dictionary of dictionaries, where the keys would be the names of the teams, and the values - your original dictionaries (which can be simply lists, BTW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you assign the dict to another var called 'single_dictionary', you actually lose the name.. So i tried to map between the league name to the original dict of teams.

Running on:

```
teams = {'NFL': {1: "Arizona Cardinals", 2: "Atlanta Falcons", 3: "Baltimore Ravens"},
         'NBA': {1:'Washington Wizards', 2:'Charlotte Hornets', 3: 'Atlanta Hawks'},
         'MLB': {1: 'Los Angeles Dogers', 2: 'Cincinnati Reds', 3: 'Toronto Blue Jays'}}

# NFL_Teams = {1: "Arizona Cardinals", 2: "Atlanta Falcons", 3: "Baltimore Ravens"}
# NBA_Teams = {1:'Washington Wizards', 2:'Charlotte Hornets', 3: 'Atlanta Hawks'}
# MLB_Teams = {1: 'Los Angeles Dogers', 2: 'Cincinnati Reds', 3: 'Toronto Blue Jays'}

def standings(reply):
    for league, single_dictionary in teams.items():
        if reply in single_dictionary.values():
            for key, value in single_dictionary.items():
                if reply == value:
                    print(key, value)
                    print(league)
            break
    else:
        print('Please Try Again')

standings('Charlotte Hornets')
```

Will print:

```
2 Charlotte Hornets
NBA
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Struggled to think that through for a solid hour.

Answer (score 2):

Are the numbers used as keys important? 
Would it make sense to have read them into the dictionaries the other way around? - then you can use a `try except KeyError` statement. This might be preferable for very large dictionaries (though this won't be the case here for teams in a league). It also might be a more object orientated way of thinking: the team name is the object identifier, whilst (I presume the numbers are current league positions?) league position is a property (and a changeable one at that). So for example (adapting Aaron_ab's answer)

```
teams = {'NFL': {"Arizona Cardinals":1, "Atlanta Falcons":2, "Baltimore Ravens":3},
     'NBA': {'Washington Wizards':1, 'Charlotte Hornets':2, 'Atlanta Hawks':3},
     'MLB': {'Los Angeles Dogers':1, 'Cincinnati Reds':2, 'Toronto Blue Jays':3}}

def standings(team):
    for league, teams_dict in teams.items():
        try:
            teams_dict[team]
            print(teams_dict[team], team)
            print(league)
            break
        except KeyError:
            continue
```

Alternatively, drop the numbers and have a dictionary of lists (where the order of the list is the current league order):

```
import numpy as np

teams = {'NFL': ["Arizona Cardinals", "Atlanta Falcons", "Baltimore Ravens"],
     'NBA': ['Washington Wizards', 'Charlotte Hornets', 'Atlanta Hawks'],
     'MLB': ['Los Angeles Dogers', 'Cincinnati Reds', 'Toronto Blue Jays']}

def standings(team):
    for league, teams_list in teams.items():
        if team in teams_list:
            print(team, np.where(np.array(teams_list)==team)[0])
            print(league)
```

Comment: Raising and catching exceptions costs much more computationally wise, try to avoid as much as possible